# Paperclip with MongoMapper in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, mongomapper

I'm trying to implement Paperclip in my first rails app, and I happen to be using rails 3 and mongodb with mongomapper.

I followed [this guide](http://www.bencurtis.com/2009/08/paperclip-and-mongomapper/) on getting there things to all work together

Just as the blog post suggests, I've put paperclip into the config/initializers directory,
I installed the gem, the gem is in the gemfile (rails 3 right), I ran the bundler.

In my user class, I've added

```
require 'paperclip'
```

When I load the app, I get the following error,

```
undefined method 'has_attached_file' for User:Class
```

The paperclip file looks like this

```
module Paperclip
  module ClassMethods
    def has_attached_file name, options = {}
      include InstanceMethods

      write_inheritable_attribute(:attachment_definitions, {}) if attachment_definitions.nil?
      attachment_definitions[name] = {:validations => []}.merge(options)

      after_save :save_attached_files
      before_destroy :destroy_attached_files

      define_callbacks :before_post_process, :after_post_process
      define_callbacks :"before_#{name}_post_process", :"after_#{name}_post_process"

      define_method name do |*args|
        a = attachment_for(name)
        (args.length > 0) ? a.to_s(args.first) : a
      end

      define_method "#{name}=" do |file|
        attachment_for(name).assign(file)
      end

      define_method "#{name}?" do
        attachment_for(name).file?
      end

      validates_each name, :logic => lambda {
        attachment = attachment_for(name)
        attachment.send(:flush_errors) unless attachment.valid?
      }
    end
  end

  module Interpolations
    # Handle string ids (mongo)
    def id_partition attachment, style
      if (id = attachment.instance.id).is_a?(Integer)
        ("%09d" % id).scan(/\d{3}/).join("/")
      else
        id.scan(/.{3}/).first(3).join("/")
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong? have I got the steps right?

Answer (score 6):

As of MongoMapper 0.11.0, Paperclip 2.5.2, and Rails 3.0.4, all you need is:

```
#your model
require 'paperclip'

class User
  include MongoMapper::Document
  include Paperclip::Glue

  has_attached_file :avatar

  key :avatar_file_name, String
end
```

You don't need a Paperclip initializer anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I just released a gem to take care of this after the above code snippets didn't quite work for later versions of paperclip and rails.

Check out [mongomapper-paperclip](https://rubygems.org/gems/mongomapper-paperclip)

Answer (score 0):

turns out I needed both

```
 
    include Paperclip
    require 'paperclip'
```

in the user.rb file.

This lead to an error where vald? was not recognized, but I commented out

```
# unless attachement.valid?
```

and now things are going better.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it working but some of the original solutions weren't working with the newly released versions.  This solution works for Rails 3.0.4, paperclip 2.3.8, and mongo_mapper 0.8.6:

model:

```
# app/models/entry_image.rb
require 'paperclip'

class EntryImage
  include MongoMapper::Document
  include Paperclip::Glue

  has_attached_file :image, :styles => {:thumb => "25x25#"}

  key :image_file_name, String

end
```

initializer

```
# config/initializers/mongo_paperclip.rb
# Code originally from 
# http://anlek.com/2010/06/getting-paperclip-to-work-with-mongomapper/
# Additional changes to work with newer version of paperclip
module Paperclip
  class << self
    def logger #:nodoc:
      MongoMapper.logger
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def has_attached_file name, options = {}
      include InstanceMethods

      write_inheritable_attribute(:attachment_definitions, {}) if attachment_definitions.nil?
      attachment_definitions[name] = {:validations => []}.merge(options)

      after_save :save_attached_files
      before_destroy :destroy_attached_files

      define_callbacks :before_post_process, :after_post_process
      define_callbacks :"before_#{name}_post_process", :"after_#{name}_post_process"

      define_method name do |*args|
        a = attachment_for(name)
        (args.length > 0) ? a.to_s(args.first) : a
      end

      define_method "#{name}=" do |file|
        attachment_for(name).assign(file)
      end

      define_method "#{name}?" do
        attachment_for(name).file?
      end

      validates_each name, :logic => lambda {|record|
        attachment = record.attachment_for(name)
        attachment.send(:flush_errors)
      }
    end
  end

  module Interpolations
    # Handle string ids (mongo)
    def id_partition attachment, style
      if (id = attachment.instance.id).is_a?(Integer)
        ("%09d" % id).scan(/\d{3}/).join("/")
      else
        id.scan(/.{3}/).first(3).join("/")
      end
    end
  end
end
```